# Windows Forms : UP/DOWN arrow works only when another button is "enabled"

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a Windows Form application. It has a button `BRIGHTNESS`, `UP ARROW` and `DOWN ARROW`. Once I press `BRIGHTNESS` followed by `UP ARROW`/`DOWN ARROW`, it changes the brightness.

Now What I want to do is associate a timer (5 sec) after which if you press just `UP ARROW`/`DOWN ARROW` nothing happens.

I am new to Windows Forms. What is the way to acheive this.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> What I want to do is associate a timer after which if you press just UP ARROW nothing happens.

I think this means that while the operator keeps pressing the button down, some function has to be repeatedly called, for a maximum of time.

For instance: while ArrowDown button is held down, the brightness increases several times, for a maximum of 5 seconds. After which the button does nothing anymore until the button is released.

Furthermore: you don't want to call BrightNessUp continuously, because that could make it increase too fast. You want to call BrightNessUp for instance every 100 msec.

So you need two TimeSpans and two methods to call

- MaxHoldDown: after this time elapses the button won't do anything
- RepetitionTime: the brightness will be increased every repetitionTime.
- void BrightnessUp();
- void BrightNessDown()

When the button is pressed down, you need to generate an event. Every subscriber to this event knows that he has to take action. This event has to be generated every RepetitionTime until the button is released, for a maximum of MaxHoldDown.

Note, that a button can also be pressed using the keyboard, but you can't hold it down with the keyboard. So you don't have to react on keyboard.

But let's first create a class that will repetitively call a method. To keep the UI responsive, I will create it using async-await

```
class RepetitiveCaller
{
    public TimeSpan RepetitionTime {get; set;}
    public Action Action {get; set;}

    // asynchronously calls MethodToCall every RepetitionTime
    public async Task CallAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var delayTask = Task.Delay(this.RepetitionTime, cancellationToken);
            this.Action();
            await delayTask;
        }
    }

    public async Task CallAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> actionAsync,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var delayTask = Task.Delay(this.RepetitionTime, cancellationToken);
            var actionTask = this.ActionAsync(cancellationToken);
            await Task.WhenAll (new Task[] {delayTask, actionTask});
        }
    }
}
```

I use Task.Delay this way, so I am sure that if the repetitiontime is 300 msec, that Action is called every 300 msec, independent of the time that Action takes. And if Action takes 400 msec, I'm sure that a new Action is not started before the previous one has finished.

The last method is used if you want to call an async BrightnessUpAsync method.

Now all we have to do is react on the operator starting to hold down the button

```
TimeSpan repetionTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
TimeSpan maxHoldDownTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null;

private void OnBrightnessUp () {...}
private void OnBrightnessDown () {...}

// The buttons:
private Button btnArrowUp = ...
private Button btnArrowDown = ...

// subscribe to mouse events:
btnArrowUp.OnMouseDown += OnRepetitionButtonMouseDown;
btnArrowDown.OnMouseDown += OnRepetitionButtonMouseDown;
btnArrowUp.OnMouseUp += OnRepetitionButtonMouseUp;
btnArrowDown.OnMouseUp += OnRepetitionButtonMouseUp;

private async void OneRepetitionButtonMouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Decide whether to Brightness Up or Down
    Action action;
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, btnArrowUp))
       action = OnBrightnessUp;
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, btnArrowDown))
       action = OnBrightnessDown;
    else
       return; // not my cup of tea;

    this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource
    {
        CancelAfter = this.MaxHoldDownTime,
    };

    RepetitiveCaller caller = new RepetitiveCaller
    {
         RepetitionTime = this.RepetitionTime,
         Action = action,
    }

    // async start calling repetively until the CancellationToken source says to cancel
    await caller.CallRepetitiveAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    // note: the cancellationTokenSource is disposed at MouseUp event
}
```

The above will automatically neatly stop after 5 seconds. But you also have to stop if the  button is released:

```
private async void OneRepetitionButtonMouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.CancellationTokenSource != null)
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        this.cancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
}
```

That is almost everything. You have to take care, that if the form is disposed, that the CancellationTokenSource is Cancelled and Disposed properly if it still exists. This way you know that even if the form is Disposed after an exception, that the task is stopped neatly.

Furthermore, some tasks raise a TaskCanceledException. Consider to use `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancelRequested` instead of checking `!IsCancelRequested` and catch the exception in CallRepetitiveAsync.